# Rename several files using its metadata content

Tags: regex, shell, grep, dicom, file-rename

I want to rename several files using a field in the metadata (patient names in DICOM files).

**For example:**

```
A001.dcm --> 1816.dcm
```

I found a utility called dcmdump:

```
dcmdump --search PatientName A001.dcm
```

> Will output:

```
(0010,0010) PN [TEACHINGFILE-MG-1816] # 20, 1 PatientName
```

But I want to extract the "1816" part to use it to rename the file, so I tested

```
dcmdump --search PatientName A001.dcm | grep -E "MG\-(.*?)\]" -o
```

That gave:

```
MG-1816]
```

I would like to know how can I get just the "1816" part, and use it to rename the A001.dcm file.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `grep -P (PCRE)`:

```
grep -oP "MG-\K[0-9]+"
```

OR sed:

```
sed 's/^.*MG-\([0-9]*\).*/\1/'
```